# SQL Merge Update specific attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i'm new in SQL, and i want to update a "big" db, with data from temporary, smaller db.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update_DimSomeone
AS
BEGIN
MERGE DimSomeone AS V
USING DimSomeone_temp AS T
    ON V.AltKey = T.Altkey
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND T.AltKey  <> '' THEN
    INSERT VALUES (AltKey, Param1, Param2, Param3)
WHEN MATCHED AND T.Param1 <> V.Param1 THEN  
    UPDATE SET V.Param1 = T.Param1
WHEN MATCHED AND T.Param2 <> V.Param2 THEN  
    UPDATE SET V.Param2 = T.Param2
WHEN MATCHED AND T.Param3 <> V.Param3 THEN  
    UPDATE SET V.Param3 = T.Param3

END
```

I've got the error: An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement.

I understand the message, but i dont want updating the whole row, only the attribute, which is not the same. (e.g. Customer with AltKey 001 change your address in temp, i want to update just the Param3 (e.g.address), not the whole row.)

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you always update param1, param2 and param3? The result will be the same!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update_DimSomeone
AS
BEGIN
MERGE DimSomeone AS V
USING DimSomeone_temp AS T
    ON V.AltKey = T.Altkey
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND T.AltKey  <> '' THEN
    INSERT VALUES (AltKey, Param1, Param2, Param3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE SET V.Param1 = T.Param1,
               V.Param2 = T.Param2,
               V.Param3 = T.Param3
END
```

EDIT:
you could at least check, if any of these 3 columns has changed so you will skip completely identical rows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update_DimSomeone
AS
BEGIN
MERGE DimSomeone AS V
USING DimSomeone_temp AS T
    ON V.AltKey = T.Altkey
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND T.AltKey  <> '' THEN
    INSERT VALUES (AltKey, Param1, Param2, Param3)
WHEN MATCHED AND (T.Param1 <> V.Param1 OR T.Param2 <> V.Param2 OR T.Param3 <> V.Param3) THEN  
    UPDATE SET V.Param1 = T.Param1,
               V.Param2 = T.Param2,
               V.Param3 = T.Param3
END
```

Comment: I have 10 parameter, this solution not takes too long?

Comment: If performance is a matter then you should think of 2 things at first: 1. Are there all necessary indexes on the table(s) / Are there any indexes that harm performance  2. Maybe it will be faster if you split your merge statement into classic update statement followed by classic insert statement

Comment: Thanks for the advice!